# Using double instead of integer with Control.Size

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to force Control.Size property to accept double type instead of integer? If not, is there an alternative?
I'm using Labels to represent values with decimal numbers.

Comment: You can cast your double values to int, for example `new Size((int)w, (int)h)`. Also you can draw an string at a `PointF` location on a drawing surface. What's your requirement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's impossible since the [`Size`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.size(v=vs.110).aspx) property describes the number of pixels that the element will be displayed on. Since there is no meaning to half a pixel, there is no meaning to using [`SizeF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.sizef(v=vs.110).aspx) as the size of a control.